# Is it possible to run a cell of a databricks notebook via REST API?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-rest-api

I would like to run a notebook cell automatically via REST API to make the usability of a [dev tool we created](https://github.com/getyourguide/db-rocket) better. Is that possible in databricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by using an older API version 1.2. You need to create an execution context with [/api/1.2/contexts/create](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/1.2/index.html#create-an-execution-context) API (it requires cluster ID and what language is used), and then you can submit code using the [/api/1.2/commands/execute](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/1.2/index.html#run-a-command) API, and get command execution status using [/api/1.2/commands/status](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/1.2/index.html#get-information-about-a-command) API.  Please note that you need to keep context to execute multiple commands depending on each other...

You can find [an example](https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/master/commands/commands.go#L39) of such execution using the Go language in the source code of Databricks Terraform provider